# Flutter hardware volume key detection?

Tags: flutter, hardware, volume

All the digging so far pointed to https://github.com/flutter-moum/flutter_hardware_buttons but that is now mentioned as deprecated (see below). I tried it anyway as per their example and it didn't work on my androdid phone either.

I am writing an app and wanted to consume the physical up down volume keys to trigger sending volume controls to an audio system I use.  Is this a "new feature" request perhaps for Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old.
But You can use this:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html

Comment: Can you please provide some example, how can I use it, if I want my custom function to be called when  Volume_up or Volume_down hardware buttons pressed, and also want to prevent default behavior (volume changing).

I'm already solved it using `MethodChannel` (call my flutter code from platform-specific code), but maybe it was overengineering...

Comment: @MikhailSemikolenov Hey. I have bad news... It's bugged. Please see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91086 and this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71144#issuecomment-932224536

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you managed to make it work with method channels on ios?

Comment: @NikolaMilosevic hey i dont use iOs