# How to override power and volume buttons in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, hardware

I want to override the power or volume button and give it a custom function. I have tried hardware buttons package (https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons/example) but it is failing to build with the error:
`C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\hardware_buttons-1.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\flutter\moum\hardware_buttons\HardwareButtonsWatcherManager.kt: (74, 42): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun onActivityStarted(@NonNull p0: Activity): Unit defined in flutter.moum.hardware_buttons.EmptyActivityLifecycleCallbacks`
Which is the best way to listen to power/volume button press events in Flutter?

Answer (score 3):

You can override it by using Focus widget.

You can use onKey callback to decide when handler it or not

```
Focus(
      autofocus: true,
      canRequestFocus: true,
      onKey: (data, event) {
        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.audioVolumeUp)) {
          print("Volume up");
          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        }
        if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.audioVolumeDown)) {
          print("Volume down");
          return KeyEventResult.handled;
        }
        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      },
      child: Container(),
    );
```

UPD: Apple prohibits overriding volume buttons, so this and other options will not work on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too, and solved it using `MethodChannel` and platform-specific code.

E.g., on Android side I do this to call my flutter code:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private lateinit var channel : MethodChannel;

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "mychannel")
    }

    // using platform-specific events
    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> channel.invokeMethod("volumeBtnPressed", "volume_down")
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> channel.invokeMethod("volumeBtnPressed", "volume_up")
        }
        // return true means "prevent default behavior", so volume doesn't change and volume bar doesn't appear
        return true
    }
}
```

On Flutter side (in State class):

```dart
  static const _volumeBtnChannel =
      MethodChannel("mychannel");

  @override
  void initState() {
    _volumeBtnChannel.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
      if (call.method == "volumeBtnPressed") {
        if (call.arguments == "volume_down") {
          doMyCustomLogic();
        }
      }

      return Future.value(null);
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

NOTE
Also, @Kozubi mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65369984/flutter-hardware-volume-key-detection/) that Shortcuts class can be used somehow, but I don't understand how.