# Detect Volume key pressed with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hey I want to be able to take pictures when the user pressed on the volume down button,
like in many devices.

I am using the Flutter Camera plugin and I can take pictures through buttons that I place on the screen but I can't detect physical button clicks.

I tried to use the [Hardware buttons plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons) but it seems that it's deprecated, and there is no support for the plugin anymore.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69900037/10738238

Answer (score 2):

There is no such much-upgraded plugin now, which can help you. But for a workaround, we do have [volume_watcher: ^2.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_watcher), which gives a callback when the volume is changed.

```
VolumeWatcher.addListener((volume) {
        print("Current Volume :" + volume.toString());
    })!;
```

***Note:*** Volume carries from 0 to 1, where 0 means no volume and 1 means max volume.

Comment: I tried it on my phone (Galaxy S21) and the method invoke twice when building but after that it's not invoking the listener function when I pressed on the volume button
maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same functionality (listen to volume down, don't change volume when listening) and it didn't exist yet in Flutter so I made a plugin for it myself, you can find it here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_android_volume_keydown

It only works on Android because overriding iOS hardware buttons is not allowed by the app store guidelines.